# What is actually Magento CE 1.9.3.2?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have made a comparison between 1.9.3.1 and 1.9.3.2 in file systems and databases. There is only one notable change in sendmail.php file. All the other files have minor changes in one line, 2016 year is now 2017 and 33 file names have been changed to 1.9.3.2.

A question is rising up, what is really 1.9.3.2 release? It is promoted with a lot of security patches but is not different than 1.9.3.1 except one file sendmail.php. I expected improvements or bug fixes but nothing was found so far. Very disappointed how Magento team is managing the new versions.

Comment: "It is promoted with a lot of security patches " <- source ?

Comment: "- Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1, SUPEE-8788, SUPEE-9652"

Comment: yes that's correct. 1.9.3.1 includes every patch you just listed except SUPEE-9652

Comment: The main reason I posted the initial question was related to my customers who are already on 1.9.3.1 and having trouble with upgrading they did alone. The real difference in code is only in one file. For those who are installing from scratch a new version it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why Magento is doing this is because whenever a patch is released, they need to include it into a new release. Otherwise they are going to have to say "Hey download 1.9.3.0, then add SUPEE-8788 and SUPEE-9652". Then people that don't know how to apply patches are going to complain (and they have which is why they are doing this).

If you take a look at patch SUPEE-9652, that is where you see the sendmail.php update. The dates are changed to 2017 because this release is in 2017 and the last one is was in 2016.

The Magento 1 version policy looks like this:

1 . MAJOR . MINOR . PATCH

Answer (score 3):

**Magento CE 1.9.3.2 Release Notes**

Removal of vulnerability with the Zend framework Zend_Mail library. For more information, see Magento Security Center.

Updated the copyright year to 2017.

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1932

*PS: Magento team is totally focused on Magento 2, don't wait for Magento 1 big release right now.*